# How do i toggle between multiple classes for multiple elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to implement a set of functions on my website with multiple div objects in it, so that when I click on `Div A`, it sets the text color of the page to red through `Class A`, and when i click on `Div B`, it sets the text to green through `Class B`, and so on and so forth.

My issue is that the other classes don't unset when clicking multiple objects and one class overrides the others, so the color of the text won't switch anymore.

I've been looking for solutions and trying to use `addClass()` and `removeClass()`, but it doesn't work for some reason. Here is a snippet of my code here

```js
$(function() {
  $('.one').click(function() {
    $("h1").addClass('onetxt');
    $("h1").removeClass('twotxt, threetxt');
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('.two').click(function() {
    $("h1").addClass('twotxt');
    $("h1").removeClass('onetxt, threetxt');
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('.three').click(function() {
    $("h1").addClass('threetxt');
    $("h1").removeClass('onetxt, twotxt');
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-style: solid;
}


/*style info, ignore above here*/

.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.onetxt {
  color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: green;
}

.twotxt {
  color: green;
}

.three {
  background-color: blue;
}

.threetxt {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Sample Text</h1>

<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, and if you need more info, ask me in the replies, thank you!

**EDIT:** Here's a [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Armel081/4shnbeug/13) demonstrating the code that i currently have, my intention is for all three of the DIV elements to change the top text's color when selected in any order, with using the classes if possible.

Comment: you should better create a test example of your code in some online environment like jsfiddle, and elaborate what doesn't work and when

Comment: Use Jquery toggle: https://api.jquery.com/toggle/ . Also your click function invokes the add and remove class at the same time, thats wrong

Comment: @gtamborero would that work for setting individual CSS classes though?

Comment: @Armel081 what do you mean? Click and toggle are the same thing, but clicks only activate when click, while toggle activate and deactivates the click

Comment: @gtamborero i mean that when i click div A, it sets class A onto the text, and when i click div B, it sets class B onto the text, my problem is that when you click multiple divs the other classes don't unset so the text gets stuck on one class

Comment: @basdanny Here, i made a JSFiddle demonstrating it here https://jsfiddle.net/Armel081/4shnbeug/13/, basically it's supposed to switch the color of the top text whenever you click on one of the div's, but whenever you click one then the other, some of the colors don't select anymore, I want to make it where you can freely switch between the options and not have it get stuck like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the main issue is that `removeClass` doesn't support multiple class selectors (like 'onetxt, twotxt').  Also you aren't removing all possible classes depending on the order of clicks.

Here's a solution that might work.  I've written some helper functions which hopefully clarify what's going on.

```js
const targets = 'h1, p'
const classmap = {
  one: 'onetxt',
  two: 'twotxt',
  three: 'threetxt'
}
const allclasses = Object.values(classmap);

function clearSelection() {
  allclasses.forEach(function(clz) { $(targets).removeClass(clz) });
}

function addSelection(sel) {
    $(targets).addClass(classmap[sel]);
}

$(function() {  
    $('.one').click(function(){
      clearSelection();
      addSelection('one')
    });
});

  $(function() {  
    $('.two').click(function(){
      clearSelection();
      addSelection('two')
    });
});

  $(function() {  
    $('.three').click(function(){
      clearSelection();
      addSelection('three')
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly with my current code!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `.removeClass()` overload supports multiple argument, it only remove the first class. [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/#removeClass2) with no argument remove all the classes. This maybe the one you need.

I tweak your code a little bit, including:

1. Rename some class name. `.color-palette` is the container of all color selection. `.color` is individual color choice box.
2. Add [`data-color-name` attribu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)te to `.color`. The attribute will be used for sample-text css class assignment.
3. Simplify the click event with a single, [event-delegate handler](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). I try to decouple the add/remove class logic with the actual color name. This way if you have more color boxes to add, you do not need to copy a new set of function.
4. Define [custom css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties). E.g. (`--color-1`, `--color-2`). The same property is used for color box background and sample text font color. You don’t have to maintain colors in two different place.

```js
$('.color-palette').on('click', '.color', function(e) {
  $("#sample-text").removeClass().addClass($(e.currentTarget).data('color-name'));
});
```

```css
/* maintain the color choices here */
:root {
  --color-1: red;
  --color-2: green;
  --color-3: blue;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.color {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-style: solid;
}


/* style info, ignore above here */


/* color palette style */

.color.color-1 {
  background-color: var(--color-1);
}

.color.color-2 {
  background-color: var(--color-2);
}

.color.color-3 {
  background-color: var(--color-3);
}


/* sample text style */

#sample-text.color-1 {
  color: var(--color-1);
}

#sample-text.color-2 {
  color: var(--color-2);
}

#sample-text.color-3 {
  color: var(--color-3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="sample-text">Sample Text</h1>
<div class="color-palette">
  <div class="color color-1" data-color-name="color-1"></div>
  <div class="color color-2" data-color-name="color-2"></div>
  <div class="color color-3" data-color-name="color-3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vanilla DOM API solution based on `classList.toggle(className: string, force: boolean)`. The second parameter controls whether `toggle` works as `remove` or `add`.

```js
const classes = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
classes.forEach(clazz => {
  document.querySelector(`.${clazz}`).addEventListener('click', () => {
    classes.forEach(cl => document.querySelector('h1').classList.toggle(`${cl}txt`, cl === clazz));
  })
})
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  border-style: solid;
}


/*style info, ignore above here*/

.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.onetxt {
  color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: green;
}

.twotxt {
  color: green;
}

.three {
  background-color: blue;
}

.threetxt {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Sample Text</h1>

<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
```